# Ember.js: Reference index in itemController

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In a handlebars template, I can reference the index of an {{#each}} helper like this:

```
{{#each}}
    {{@index}}
{{/each}}
```

OR

```
{#each}}
    {{_view.contentIndex}}
{{/each}}
```

If I'm using an itemController, how can I get a reference to the index from the itemController?

```
{{#each itemController="item"}}
    {{foo}}
{{/each}}

App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  foo: function() {
   // how to get a reference to the index here?
   // this.get('@index') doesn't work
   // this.get('index') doesn't work
  }.property()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `parentController` and use `indexOf` to get the index of the current item.

```
App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  foo: function() {
    return this.parentController.indexOf(this);
  }.property('parentController.[]')
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sokukihe/1/edit

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what the '.[]' part means in the property argument?

Comment: Totally, it means if anything is added, removed, or moved around in the array this property should be considered dirty, and should be recalculated (if anyone is watching it).